# LinearLayout.removeAllViews doesn't work with programmatically created elements

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm trying to programmatically create UI elements in Android. It is working, but when I press back button and after that return to the activity that creates elements, I want to delete previous created ones. I tried the following code in my onCreate method:

```
((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainContainer)).removeAllViews();
        ((LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainContainer)).addView(generateElementsDynamically());
```

My generateElementsDynamically() method:

```
public static LinearLayout generateElementsDynamically()
    {
        LinearLayout main = new LinearLayout(context);
        main.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    main.setLayoutParams(layoutParams1);

    for (int i = 0; i < ServicesStorage.listServiceDetails.size(); i++)
    {
        LinearLayout lin = new LinearLayout(context);
        for (int j = 0; j < ServicesStorage.listServiceDetails.get(i).size(); j++)
        {
            lin.setOrientation(LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            lin.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            TextView txt = new TextView(context);
            txt.setText(ServicesStorage.listServiceDetails.get(i).get(j).toString());
            txt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            lin.addView(txt);
        }
        main.addView(lin);
    }
    return main;
}
```

Any idea what is wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found solution, though I'm not sure if it is the best.
For some reason i had to clear ServicesStorage.listServiceDetails list and then populate it again...and it's working

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to refresh UI with new datas. I would suggest you to change your design. You can use ListView and fill it your new datas. Anytime they changed you can call

`listview.notifySetDataChanged();`

Comment: No, every time this activity is created I want to draw new elements and destroy previous ones, it is not only about data in TextViews, the number of elements is always different